# Error: Invalid Adapter :idb in pouchdb + ionic 3 with using chrome (Version 63.0)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, pouchdb

I am using pouchDb +ionic 3. During creating pouchDb with ionic 3 without mention any parameter (by default: websql) it's working fine. But whenever I try to use adapter (indexedDB) like :

```
setupDB() {
 this.db = new PouchDB('Contacts', {adapter : 'idb'});
 }
```

it's thrown an error :

```
ERROR Error: Invalid Adapter: idb
at new PouchDB$5 (VM46 vendor.js:118540)
```

Please Help.

Comment: Why do you say it's defaulting to websql? It should default to IndexedDB in browsers that support both.

Comment: @Flimzy means when i use like this :  this.db = new PouchDB('Contacts'); it use websql and its working fine but when i use like this : this.db = new PouchDB('Contacts', {adapter : 'idb'}); it's throw an error : ERROR Error: Invalid Adapter: idb
at new PouchDB$5 (VM46 vendor.js:118540)

Comment: I understand that it works when you don't specify the adaptor. My question is: How do you know it's defaulting to websql? Because according to the documentation, it should be defaulting to IndexedDB.

Comment: @Flimzy : i console the this.db like this : setupDB() {
 this.db = new PouchDB('Contacts); console.log(this.db); // which print "websql"
 }

Comment: Thanks. Then my guess is that for some reason, IndexedDB is not available in your particular case.

Comment: @Flimzy Thanks but how to fix that issues?

Comment: Use a browser/platform that supports IndexedDB?

Comment: @Flimzy i am using latest version of chrome

Comment: @Priyank any chance you are using Chrome dev tools and select iOS as emulator there? I think when I played aroudn with this myself a while ago this is what I noted - if I do emulator of Android - idb works in this case. If I do iOS - then this issue is there...:(  check this issue out for potential solution: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/6501

Comment: also check this one out: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/6946

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a known issue specifically for iOS mobile.
You can see this being discussed in this thread:
https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/6946

Seems like the fix is in flight:
https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/7085

So we should upgrade soon and this will hopefully resolve it.

UPDATE: ALSO make sure your iOS browser is NOT in incognito mode. Such modes do not allow persistence of data.